# Некорректно работает код меню

Tags: jquery

вот такой код, что делать если он раскрывает все под-меню?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menu-item").click(function() {
    $(".menu-item .sub-menu").slideToggle("slow");
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="menu-item-71" class="menu-item menu-item-active has-child"><a href="#" aria-current="page">Главная</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
    <li id="menu-item-102" class="menu-item"><a href="#
    ">Мой аккаунт</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Может Вы приложите HTML? Но вообще ничего удивительно, так как у Вас указано `$(".menu-item .sub-menu")`,  и получается что Вы работаете со всеми саб меню, а не с конкретно тем на которое нажали. Конкретно к WordPress это не имеет отношения. Замените `$(".menu-item .sub-menu")` на `$(this).find('.sub-menu')`

Comment: так, это анимация корявая, неуместна здесь. Благодарствую большое